Seeking Advice: Possible Solutions for New Software Portal
In short where the software is used for
We manage extensive data collection, process complex forms and surveys, and provide a secure platform for users to submit requests, modifications, and mandatory reports. Our current system is custom-built, but we are looking to upgrade to a more scalable and efficient solution to better meet our operational needs and future growth.The required software must meet the following functional and technical requirements:
Workflow

Identity, Access & Authorization Management: User account management, including role-based access.
Requests and Modifications: Forms for requesting, modifying, and canceling products and services.
Auditing and Data Integrity: Logging all changes and ensuring data quality.

Forms

Data Collection: Support for basic forms, data uploads, and validation.
Surveys and Questionnaires: Complex forms with routing logic and input validation.
Notifications: Support for notifications with and without attachments.

Portal

Basic Information and Data Management: Users can view and manage their data.
Message Box: Support for file uploads, notifications, chat, and video calling.
Calendar Viewing: Displaying and generating calendars.

Technical Components

API and Web Services: Interaction with external systems.
Communication: Support for email, chat, and possibly chatbots and SIP.

Additional Requirements

Cloud-first: Preference for SaaS solutions over PaaS and IaaS.
Secure and Reliable: Security and reliability at all levels.
No Customization: Preference for standard solutions to minimize maintenance costs.
Standard Integration Options: Integration with the Microsoft Azure stack (e.g., CRM, SharePoint).

Possible outcome could be;

A combination of SaaS solutions
A low-code development platform.
A combination of a low-code platform and SaaS.

If you need more information, please let me know and i'm happy to share.

We recently met with a company that has a low-code platform that might be a good fit for you. Most of their clients are in e-commerce domain as they have out-of-box functionality for modules like product and content management, but their core platform has all these requirements as far as I know. Check out their web-site https://rierino.com and if you are interested I can introduce you over an e-mail.
